# OpenWRT doesn't boot

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, openwrt, u-boot

I have a RT5350F router device (Hardware is almost the same as Nexx WT1520). It used to run Zyxel Keenetic 4G II firmware, and now I decided to reflash OpenWRT to it.

I tried a lot of versions, and all of them don't boot any further than this:

```
U-Boot 1.1.3 (Apr 11 2013 - 00:10:51)
Board: Ralink APSoC DRAM:  16 MB
relocate_code Pointer at: 80fb4000
spi_wait_nsec: 42
spi device id: c2 20 16 c2 20 (2016c220)
find flash: MX25L3205D
raspi_read: from:30000 len:1000
.*** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

============================================
Ralink UBoot Version: 3.6.0.0
--------------------------------------------
ASIC 5350_MP (Port5<->None)
DRAM_CONF_FROM: Boot-Strapping
DRAM_TYPE: SDRAM
DRAM_SIZE: 128 Mbits
DRAM_WIDTH: 16 bits
DRAM_TOTAL_WIDTH: 16 bits
TOTAL_MEMORY_SIZE: 16 MBytes
Flash component: SPI Flash
Date:Apr 11 2013  Time:00:10:51
============================================
icache: sets:256, ways:4, linesz:32 ,total:32768
dcache: sets:128, ways:4, linesz:32 ,total:16384

 ##### The CPU freq = 360 MHZ ####
 estimate memory size =16 Mbytes

Please choose the operation:
   1: Load system code to SDRAM via TFTP.
   2: Load system code then write to Flash via TFTP.
   3: Boot system code via Flash (default).
   4: Entr boot command line interface.
   7: Load Boot Loader code then write to Flash via Serial.
   9: Load Boot Loader code then write to Flash via TFTP.                     0

3: System Boot system code via Flash.
## Booting image at bc050000 ...
raspi_read: from:50000 len:40
.   Image Name:   MIPS OpenWrt Linux-3.18.45
   Created:      2017-03-05  12:30:01 UTC
   Image Type:   MIPS Linux Kernel Image (lzma compressed)
   Data Size:    1087633 Bytes =  1 MB
   Load Address: 80000000
   Entry Point:  80000000
raspi_read: from:50040 len:109891
.................   Verifying Checksum ... OK
   Uncompressing Kernel Image ... OK
No initrd
## Transferring control to Linux (at address 80000000) ...
## Giving linux memsize in MB, 16

Starting kernel ...

[    0.000000] Linux version 3.18.45 (wayfarer@VirtualBox) (gcc version 4.8.3 (O                                                                                                                                                             penWrt/Linaro GCC 4.8-2014.04 r49389) ) #3 Sun Mar 5 14:29:13 EET 2017
[    0.000000] SoC Type: Ralink RT5350 id:1 rev:3
[    0.000000] bootconsole [early0] enabled
[    0.000000] CPU0 revision is: 0001964c (MIPS 24KEc)
[    0.000000] MIPS: machine is Nexx WT1520
[    0.000000] Determined physical RAM map:
[    0.000000]  memory: 02000000 @ 00000000 (usable)
[    0.000000] Initrd not found or empty - disabling initrd
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x00000000-0x01ffffff]
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000-0x01ffffff]
[    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x00000000-0x01ffffff]
```

I reflashed U-boot as well, which didn't really help.
Some other OpenWRT firmwares boot, but crash right away, saying "Not enough RAM".

Comment: "Almost the same" isn't good enough unless you really know what you're doing. Linux on embedded devices mostly doesn't detect and adapt to different hardware like it does on PCs; all the details have to be baked into the build ahead of time. Which means any difference at all between the two boards needs to be accounted for or nothing will work. And there's certainly some difference, given that the WT1510U has 32MB RAM, and you can see Linux trying to map 32MB, but your device only has 16MB.

Comment: Actually, my device has 32MB of RAM. The SDRAM chip is EM63A165TS. No idea why it shows 16.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing code. Requests for recommendations, tutorials, research, tools, libraries, code and debugging embedded systems are off-topic. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.